# Simulate a Graphics Card for a Windows VPS with no Graphics Card

Tags: windows, vps, graphics

Considering you have a VPS Windows Server and want to run an application that requires to have a **graphics card having 64MB of RAM**, could you somehow simulate that graphics card to run the application or is it inevitable to install a physical graphics card? I thought about utilizing RAM or CPU partially as Graphics Card.

The Application has to choose the particular graphics card to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simulate a card, if h/w GPU is missing. But it is possible to assign VRAM depending on host's hypervisor.
For example in Hyper-V, you can use RemoteFX vGPU with up to 1024MB VRAM.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a working solution for me.